# Moving a parameter to avoid multiple solutions

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

If $p,q$ are coprime polynomials in $\Bbb R[X]$ and $a\in\Bbb R$ then if the equation
$$
\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}=a
$$
has a multiple solution (that is $x_0$ solving $p=aq$ -we can write this way locally, since $p,q$ coprime implies $p(x_0)\neq0\neq q(x_0)$- such that $x_0$ solves $p'=aq'$ as well), then we can arbitrarily move $a$ a little to make $x_0$ a simple solution.

Does it hold even in the complex case? That is, when $p,q$ are coprime polynomials in $\Bbb C[X]$ and $a\in\Bbb C$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roots with a multiplicity greater than one must satisfy:

$$
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
f(x, a) &= p(x) - a\,q(x) &= 0
\\ g(x, a) &= p'(x) - a\,q'(x) &= 0
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$

The condition for the system to have solutions is that the [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) $\,\text{res}_x(f,g)=0\,$, which is a polynomial equation in $\,a\,$.

It follows that there are finitely many values of $a$ for which the original equation has a multiple root. Then, if $a$ takes one of those values, any small enough perturbation will cause the roots to become distinct.

Comment: Wait a minute: call $w_0$ the solution of $p-aq=0$. If I move $a$ to make the resultant $\neq0$ then the original equation will be different and $w_0$ wouldn't be still a solution, in general. I mean, clearly $w_0=w_0(a)$. The resultant is a polynomial in $w$ and in $a$ and for every $a$ we can find $w=w(a)$ making the resultant 0, so there could be infinitely many values for $a$.

Comment: Let me reformulate the question: is it true that the equation $p-aq=0$ has multiple roots only a finite number of values of $a$?

Comment: @Joe The resultant is a polynomial in $\,a\,$, which has finitely many roots. For each of those roots, the original equation will have at least one multiple root $\,w=w(a)\,$, but that doesn't change the fact that the resultant is a polynomial in $\,a\,$ alone, which can only be zero for finitely many values of $\,a\,$. For all other $\,a\,$ the resultant is non-zero, so all roots of the original equation are simple roots.

Comment: @Joe In the real case, the intuition is that a multiple root occurs iff the horizontal line $\,y=a\,$ has a tangency point in common with the graph $\,y=r(x)=p(x)/q(x)\,$. But a rational function $\,r(x)\,$ can only have finitely many critical points where the tangent is horizontal.

Comment: @dvix: clear. Thank you very much